# PySide6: How do I resize a QLabel playing a QMovie and maintain the movie's original aspect ratio?

Tags: python, qt, resize, pyside6, qmovie

I would be very grateful for your help specifying the re-sizing behaviour of a `Pyside6` `QLabel` displaying a `QMovie` such that the original aspect ratio of the movie (e.g. a .gif file) is maintained when the size of the parent `QLabel` is changed.

These two questions have answers that detail the process for a `QLabel` displaying a `QPixmap`:

[How to Autoresize QLabel pixmap keeping ratio without using classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041941/how-to-autoresize-qlabel-pixmap-keeping-ratio-without-using-classes)

[Pyside6, How do I resize a QLabel without loosing the size aspect ratio? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72188903/pyside6-how-do-i-resize-a-qlabel-without-loosing-the-size-aspect-ratio)

Both make use of the `QPixmap.scaled(w, h, aspectMode, mode)` method ([link to docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtGui/QPixmap.html#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap.scaled)), which has a parameter `aspectMode` that can be set to `Qt.KeepAspectRatio`.

Unlike `QPixmap` objects, `QMovie` objects do not have a `.scaled()` method.  They do have a `QMovie.setScaledSize(size)` method ([link to docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtGui/QMovie.html#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QMovie.setScaledSize)), which accepts a `QSize` object as its only parameter.

My question therefore becomes how can I build a `QSize` object with the same aspect ratio as my original .gif file, but scaled to be as big as possible within its parent `QLabel` , and update this whenever the `QLabel` is resized by the user?

Here is the custom class `SclaedLabel` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72188904/23014932) adapted as far as I can for scaling the `QLabel.movie` rather than the `QLabel.Pixmap`:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt


class ScaledLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._movie = self.movie()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.setMovie(self._movie)

    def setMovie(self, movie):
        if movie:
            original_size = movie.scaledSize()
            size_scaled = original_size.scale(self.size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            return QLabel.setMovie(self, self._movie.setScaledSize(size_scaled))
```

Unfortunately, `movie.scaledSize()` is returning a `QSize` of `(-1, -1)` for my gif file, which causes `size_scaled` to become `None` .

I would therefore appreciate your help obtaining a `QSize` object for my original movie (.gif file), and any suggestions on its implementation to obtain the desired QMovie KeepAspectRatio scaling behaviour.

Comment: I don't see `.gif` in your code. Maybe you should get size when you load it. Maybe create `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and run it - to see problem and test some solutions.

Comment: @furas In reality, the source gif file is irrelevant: `scaledSize()` is only set as soon as `setScaledSize()` is called for formats that don't support scaling natively (which is the case for GIF), otherwise it's an invalid size (`QSize(-1, -1)`).

Comment: The ```scaledSize()``` just returns what you set by the ```setScaledSize()```. Use the ```frameRect().size()```. Also don't forget to call a method for the ```size()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the QMovie class doesn't provide a valid `scaledSize()` for GIF images, meaning that it will always return an invalid size (aka `QSize(-1, -1)`) unless `setScaledSize()` has been called explicitly with a valid size.

Calling `setScaledSize()` alone would be inadequate, though, because it would also cause the QLabel to use that size as its *minimum* size, so the label may only become bigger and bigger, but never smaller.

Similarly to what normally is done with QLabel for fixed aspect ratio QPixmaps, the best approach is to both set a reasonable minimum size, and override the paint event ensuring that the content considers the minimum aspect ratio.

For optimization reasons (and to avoid delays in resizing, since the pixmap is cached and not updated until a new frame is shown), the painting is done in two ways: if the possible size doesn't match the current scaled size, we internally paint a scaled pixmap, otherwise we follow the default painting implementation by copying what QLabel does in the sources.

```py
class ScaledLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._movieSize = QSize()
        self._minSize = QSize()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        if self._minSize.isValid():
            return self._minSize
        return super().minimumSizeHint()

    def setMovie(self, movie):
        if self.movie() == movie:
            return
        super().setMovie(movie)

        if not isinstance(movie, QMovie) or not movie.isValid():
            self._movieSize = QSize()
            self._minSize = QSize()
            self.updateGeometry()
            return

        cf = movie.currentFrameNumber()
        state = movie.state()
        movie.jumpToFrame(0)
        rect = QRect()
        for i in range(movie.frameCount()):
            movie.jumpToNextFrame()
            rect |= movie.frameRect()

        width = rect.x() + rect.width()
        height = rect.y() + rect.height()

        self._movieSize = QSize(width, height)
        if width == height and False:
            if width < 4:
                self._minSize = QSize(width, width)
            else:
                self._minSize = QSize(4, 4)
        else:
            minimum = min(width, height)
            maximum = max(width, height)
            ratio = maximum / minimum
            base = min(4, minimum)
            self._minSize = QSize(base, round(base * ratio))
            if minimum == width:
                self._minSize.transpose()

        movie.jumpToFrame(cf)
        if state == movie.MovieState.Running:
            movie.setPaused(False)
        self.updateGeometry()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        movie = self.movie()
        if not isinstance(movie, QMovie) or not movie.isValid():
            super().paintEvent(event)
            return

        qp = QPainter(self)
        self.drawFrame(qp)

        cr = self.contentsRect()
        margin = self.margin()
        cr.adjust(margin, margin, -margin, -margin)

        style = self.style()
        alignment = style.visualAlignment(self.layoutDirection(), self.alignment())
        maybeSize = self._movieSize.scaled(cr.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        if maybeSize != movie.scaledSize():
            movie.setScaledSize(maybeSize)
            style.drawItemPixmap(
                qp, cr, alignment, 
                movie.currentPixmap().scaled(cr.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            )

        else:
            style.drawItemPixmap(
                qp, cr, alignment, 
                movie.currentPixmap()
            )
```

Comment: It works beautifully!  Thank you very much for your time and effort @musicamante.  I just needed to change one thing:  At the end of your definition for `setMovie`, I needed to change `if state == movie.Running:` to `if state == movie.MovieState.Running:`.  It then works perfectly.  Let me know if you have any further comments on this.

Comment: @Tranquille Yeah, sorry, I forgot that this was for Qt6, which prefers/requests (in PySide6) or requires (in PyQt6) the full namespace of Enums.